# Error when I remove part of a where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2, where-clause

I'm in SQL Server 2008 R2 and I'm working in Management Studio. I have a query that runs just fine, but when I **remove** a part of the where clause then I get an error that says "Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Line 6
Error converting data type varchar to numeric."
This error comes when I remove the fourth to last line:

```
AND INSCOMP.BINNO = '610502'
```

The full query is below:

```
SET @StartDate = '2020-01-01'
SET @EndDate = '2020-04-30'
SET @Year = '2020'
--149
SELECT 
OT.COMMENTS AS [Order Comments],
CONVERT(CHAR(10),TICKCI.DELIVDATE,101) AS [Delivery Date],
TICKCI.TICKNO,
CAST((TICKCI.DELIVDATE - NCPDP.DATEFILLED)AS NUMERIC(100)) AS [Turn Around Time],
POPUPDATA.TEXT_ AS [TEAM],
ROSTER.ORG AS [REFERRAL SOURCE],
HR.MRN AS [MRN],
HR.FIRST_NAME,
HR.LAST_NAME,
RTRIM(HR.LAST_NAME) + ', ' + RTRIM(HR.FIRST_NAME) AS FULLNAME,
convert(char(10),NCPDP.DATEFILLED,101) as [Date Filled],
CAST(@ENDDATE-@STARTDATE AS NUMERIC(36,2))/30 AS [# OF MONTHS],
NCPDP.BILLNO as [INVOICE #],
PARTS.NAME_ AS [Drug Name],
convert(char(10),HR.DOB,101) AS [DATE OF BIRTH],
HR.SEX,
HR.ADDRESS,
HR.STATE,
NCPDP.RXORIGIN,
NCPDP.RXNO,
NCPDP.NDC,
--NCPDP.DRUGNAME,
PARTS.SUPPLIED,
CAST(NCPDP.[QTYDISP] AS NUMERIC(36,2)) as [Qty Dispensed],
CAST(NCPDP.DAYSSUPPLY AS NUMERIC(36,0)) as [Days Supplied],
NCPDP.NEWREFILL,
NCPDP.PRESCRIBER,
NCPDP.ID_ AS [DR. NPI],
DOCTORS.PH_ADDRESS,
DOCTORS.PH_CITY,
DOCTORS.PH_STATE,
DOCTORS.PH_ZIP,
DOCTORS.PH_SPEC,
PATINS.POLICY AS [PT INSURANCE ID #],
NCPDP.COST AS [AMOUNT BILLED],
(NCPDP.EXPECTED-NCPDP.COPAY) AS [INSURANCE PAY],
NCPDP.COPAY AS [PT COPAY],
NCPDP.EXPECTED AS [TOTAL PAID],
--'$' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),cast((NCPDP.COST)as money),1)AS [AMOUNT BILLED],
--'$' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),cast((NCPDP.EXPECTED-NCPDP.COPAY)as money),1)AS [INSURANCE PAY],
--'$' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),cast((NCPDP.COPAY)as money),1) AS [PT COPAY],
--'$' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),cast((NCPDP.EXPECTED)as money),1) AS [TOTAL PAID],
ICDMASTERLIST.DESCRIPTION AS DIAGNOSIS1,
ICDMASTERLIST.CODE AS ICD10,
ICDMASTERLIST.CODE + ' - ' + ICDMASTERLIST.DESCRIPTION AS [ICD10 + Description],
CASE 
        WHEN POPUPDATA.TEXT_ IN('CINJ Onc', '%ONC%','NBONC', 'MMCONC', 'CINJ Heme','SBOnc','*CINJ Study','*Mail Order', 'LAKE', '%CINJ%') THEN 'Oncology'
        WHEN POPUPDATA.TEXT_ IN('GREENVILLE', 'NBI-ID', 'NBS-ID') THEN 'Infectious Disease'
        WHEN POPUPDATA.TEXT_ IN( 'NBK', 'SBK','NBH', 'RWH', 'NBS-HT', 'RWPK', 'RWK', 'PAK', 'NBL','KID','NBHK','HMK','SBKP') THEN 'Transplant'
        WHEN POPUPDATA.TEXT_ LIKE 'OTHER' THEN 'Misc'
        WHEN POPUPDATA.TEXT_ IN('NBI-IC') THEN 'Rheumatology'     
        ELSE POPUPDATA.TEXT_ END AS [Therapy Type],
INSCOMP.ORG,
'Yes' AS [FDA Approved],
INSCOMP.BINNO,
PARTS.UBREVCODE
FROM LABLOG
LEFT OUTER JOIN HR
ON HR.DELFLAG = 0 AND HR.MRN = LABLOG.LINK
LEFT OUTER JOIN NCPDP 
ON NCPDP.DELFLAG = 0 AND NCPDP.LABLOGNO = LABLOG.CPK_LABLOG
LEFT OUTER JOIN CLAIMS 
ON CLAIMS.DELFLAG = 0 AND CLAIMS.CFK_INVOICES = NCPDP.BILLNO AND CLAIMS.CFK_INSCOMP = NCPDP.INSNO
LEFT OUTER JOIN POPUPDATA
ON POPUPDATA.DELFLAG = 0 AND POPUPDATA.CPK_POPUPDATA = HR.CFK_POPUPDATA_ENTTEAMS
LEFT OUTER JOIN ROSTER 
ON ROSTER.DELFLAG = 0 AND ROSTER.CPK_ROSTER = HR.CFK_REFSOURC
left outer join ICDPATIENT  
on ICDPATIENT.cfk_hr = HR.mrn AND ICDPATIENT.RANK = 1
left outer join ICDMASTERLIST
on ICDPATIENT.CFK_ICDMASTERLIST_ICD10 = ICDMASTERLIST.CPK_ICDMASTERLIST
LEFT OUTER JOIN INSCOMP
ON INSCOMP.DELFLAG = 0 AND INSCOMP.NO = NCPDP.INSNO
LEFT OUTER JOIN OT
ON OT.DELFLAG = 0 AND OT.NO = LABLOG.ORDERNO
LEFT OUTER JOIN PARTS
ON PARTS.DELFLAG = 0 AND PARTS.NO = OT.INVNO
LEFT OUTER JOIN PATINS 
ON PATINS.DELFLAG = 0 AND CLAIMS.CFK_PATINS = PATINS.CPK_PATINS
LEFT OUTER JOIN DOCTORS
ON DOCTORS.DELFLAG = 0 AND DOCTORS.NO = OT.PH_NO
LEFT OUTER JOIN TICKC
ON tickc.DELFLAG=0 and tickc.NEXTCODE = LABLOG.SCRIPTEXT AND CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),TICKC.CREATEDON, 20) = CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),LABLOG.CREATEDON, 20)
LEFT OUTER join TICKCI
ON tickci.DELFLAG= 0 and tickci.TICKNO = tickc.TICKNO
WHERE HR.DELFLAG = 0 AND NCPDP.[DATEFILLED] BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate 
AND NCPDP.[EXPECTED]<>0.00 
AND INSCOMP.BINNO = '610502'
AND NOT INSCOMP.ORG LIKE '%D-%'
AND NCPDP.[CLAIMSTAT] <> 'R' AND NCPDP.[CLAIMSTAT] <> 'T' AND NCPDP.[CLAIMSTAT] <> 'X' AND HR.SITENO<>1  AND PARTS.UBREVCODE <> 'X   '
ORDER BY tickci.DELIVDATE ASC
```

Any help is appreciated.
Please and thank you

Comment: this doesn't look like code for mysql more for sql server

Comment: Table DDL with enough data to replicate the error would be helpful.  By any chance, is NCPDP.[DATEFILLED] a string instead of a DATE?

Comment: I'd look to see what values are in NCPDP.[EXPECTED] where INSCOMP.BINNO <> '610502'.  It seems like it is an issue converting a varcar to an int, maybe an empty value or a decimal point is a period.  That or try running it without AND INSCOMP.BINNO = '610502' and include 0.00 in ' '

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @DreadedFrost, your comment made me go check that table and sure enough there's a column in that table called dayssupply that should theoretically never be blank but there were a few values that were. I ran an update statement to change those blank values to zero's and everything is working fine now.